# CSS: Padding/margin issues. What's causing this staggering?

Tags: html, css, format, margin, padding

I'm essentially trying to replicate the webpage output for this [assignment](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/16wi/homework/2/spec.pdf). Pictures used in webpage are [here](https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/).

The issue is the spacing between each of the elements. It's just a bit off and I can't figure out why. There is supposed to be 20pt of vertical spacing between each. I believe that

```
.reviewer-info {
    padding-bottom: 20pt;
}
```

should have appropriately implemented, but there's clearly still a huge disparity. Is there something I'm missing?

[My output](http://oi63.tinypic.com/29fxh7k.jpg)

[Desired output](http://oi65.tinypic.com/4hcody.jpg)

[My output overlayed over desired output](http://oi67.tinypic.com/x0pu04.jpg)

```css
#banner {
 height: 50px;
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbannerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#banner img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

body {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/moviebg.png);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10pt;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#column-left, #column-right {
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 47%;
}

#column-left {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

#column-right {
 float: right;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
 margin: auto;
 width: 800px;
}

#date {
 background-color: #A2B964;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

h1, .reviewer-text {
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlargebg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 height: 83px;
 font-size: 48pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}

#logo img {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.publication {
 font-style: italic;
}

#reviews {
 width: 550px;
}

.reviewer-info {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.reviewer-info img, .reviewer-text img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.reviewer-text {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

#general-overview {
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #A2B964;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 float: right;
}

#general-overview dt {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10pt;
 padding-left: 10pt;
}

#general-overview dd {
 padding-left: 10pt;
 padding-right: 10pt;
}

#general-overview ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#validators {
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="movie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="rotten.gif" />
 
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id = "banner">
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" />
  </div>

  <h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>

  <div id="container">
   <div id="general-overview">
    <div>
     <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
    </div>

    <dl>
     <dt>STARRING</dt>
     <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

     <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
     <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

     <dt>RATING</dt>
     <dd>PG</dd>

     <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
     <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

     <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
     <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

     <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
     <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

     <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
     <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

     <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
     <dd>90 mins</dd>

     <dt>GENRE</dt>
     <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

     <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
     <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

     <dt>LINKS</dt>
     <dd>
      <br />
      <ul>
       <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>

      </ul>
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </div>
   
   <div id="reviews"> 
    <div id="logo">
     <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" />
     33%
    </div>

    <div id="column-left">
     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Peter Debruge <br />
      <span class="publication">Variety</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
      <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Todd Gilchrist <br />
      <span class="publication">IGN Movies</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>It stinks!</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Jay Sherman (unemployed)
      <br />
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Joshua Tyler <br />
      <span class="publication">CinemaBlend.com</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>This movie sucks because reasons.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      T. Tally Nobias <br />
      <span class="publication">objectivereviews.com</span>
     </p>
    </div>

    <div id="column-right">
     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Jeannette Catsoulis <br />
      <span class="publication">New York Times</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Ed Gonzalez <br />
      <span class="publication">Slant Magazine</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
      <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Mark Palermo <br />
      <span class="publication">Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      Steve Rhodes <br />
      <span class="publication">Internet Reviews</span>
     </p>

     <p class="reviewer-text">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
      <q>This movie is literally the worst movie ever. I'm not going to explain why. -10000000/10.</q>
     </p>
     <p class="reviewer-info">
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
      A. Rheal Kritik <br />
      <span class="publication">Facade Inc.</span>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <p id="date">(1-10) of 88</p>
  </div>

  <div id="validators">
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" /></a><br />
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" /></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's because the `padding` on your `p` element is ignoring the `image`. And also, it only concern about the `padding` of your text inside the `p` element. If you observe the single-lined text in your `p` element,it only fits the `padding` of content not the `image`, and multi-lined text covers the illusion of ignoring the `image` because `texts` are below the `image`. Try adding `padding-bottom=15px` and you will achieved your desired output but as you can see it only works for single-lined content and it looks uneven with multi-lined. Do something about your `content` and `image`.

Answer (score 0):

The `float:left;` is causing the issue for you. Two changes will likely fix the issue:

1. Add `align="left"` to the icons `img` tag.
2. Change the CSS for the `img`s within the `.reviewer-text` to use `margin` and `vertical-align: middle;`

   .reviewer-info img, 
   .reviewer-text img {
     margin-right: 4px;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
     vertical-align: middle;
   }

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/tn1Lsxva/).

Comment: Doing this actually seems to distort the output further from the desired output. Is there something else I could try?

Comment: You're talking about the icons in the text bubbles correct?

Comment: The icons in the text bubbles are aligned correctly now but now the spacing between the text bubbles and the text itself is completely different from the desired output

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, for this particular assignment, all of the style has to be expressed in the CSS. I can't adjust the img tags, and can only add organizational tags like div and span.

Comment: Nonetheless, it still doesn't seem to be working for some reason. The formatting for the review section seems to be working as it should, but the formatting for the general overview section and the validator links is messed up

Comment: Didn't realize there was more than one issue.

Comment: Sorry for making things unclear. :( The initial issue was the spacing and the icons. I'd just like for those to be fixed without the rest of the webpage's formatting being affected.

Comment: Essentially just making it as close to the desired output as possible

Comment: Sorry, it's not that there are multiple issues. There's just one. It's just that the solution you proposed seems to create another issue at the same time specifically that the general overview has no style or formatting anymore

Comment: Ah, I pasted your CSS and HTML directly into the fiddle so it must be missing something.

Comment: Hmm, I just double-checked and it looks like it was missing the header. Does that make a difference on JSFiddle now?